# dynamic contextual filters block

Tags: views

I am really stuck at this pont can anybody help me out

if i am in the domain.com/computers/all/brand/acer
i want to create a contextual filter block with urls like say

computers/com1/brand/acer
computers/com2/brand/acer
computers/com3/brand/acer
computers/com4/brand/acer

com vocabulary contains these com1, com2, com3, com4 items
acer has to be dynamically taken from url

I have tried a lot but ended up with
computers/com1/brand/all
computers/com2/brand/all

or i ended up with

computers/all/brand/acer/com1
computers/all/brand/acer/com1

can anybody guide me

Comment: What do you mean by "acer has to be dynamically taken from url"?